# Ler a propriedade SelectedValue de um ComboBox com Livebindings

Tags: delphi, combobox, firemonkey, delphi-10, binding

Preciso recuperar o valor da propriedade **SelectedValue** de um Combobox que esta ligado a minha tabela através do Livebindings.

[image: Ligação do Livebindings]

Já vi sugestões para ligar o SelectedValue a propriedade TAG do Objeto ao qual estiver fazendo o Livebindings ou a um outro objeto, como Label, quando o Livebindings ligar a um campo de uma tabela (chave estrangeira por exemplo).
Mas gostaria de encontrar uma solução mais padronizada, esta tem uma aparência de "gambiarra".